# How to search for an array fragment inside bigger an array, possibily using threshold

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have original picture and I need to search for picture fragments inside the original picture. I looked at already existing solution in PIL and CV, they are not transparent and don't work as precisely. I hoped that there might be function in numpy that could do the same, also using threshold.

```
full picture:
0   0   0
0   1   0
0   0.9 0
0   1   0
0   0   0
```

```
fragment:
1
1
1
```

fragment matches full picture

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you might search for this:
https://cvisiondemy.com/extract-roi-from-image-with-python-and-opencv/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the convolutions kernels, preferably by appending your fragment to the square matrix, so fragment:

```
1,
0.9,
1
```

becomes:

```
0, 1, 0,
0, 0.9, 0,
0, 1, 0
```

Then you simply convolve the fragment with the full picture and search for the maximums -- that will be the places where your fragment is found.

You may want to check:
https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html